# How to check image transparency with Python for images stored as URLs?

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-requests

I have csv file with urls to my images. I want to check which image has transparent logo. For some rows there are no urls provided, for some rows urls don't open (that's why I added requests exceptions).

The below code works for the first 3 rows in my csv file. However, for the fourth row which has no url and is blank it throws the following error:

```
NoTransparent!
Transparent
NoTransparent!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/transparency.py", line 13, in <module>
    pic = plt.imread(x)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2230, in imread
    return matplotlib.image.imread(fname, format)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 1486, in imread
    with img_open(fname) as image:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 107, in __init__
self._open()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py", line 636, in _open
if self.fp.read(8) != _MAGIC:
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'read'
```

my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.read_csv('/path/to/my/input.csv')
urls = df.T.values.tolist()[3]
msgid =  df.T.values.tolist()[0]
imgType=[]

for x in urls:
    if x == '':
        continue
    try:
        pic = plt.imread(x)
        if pic.shape[2] == 3:
            imgType.append("Transparent")
            print("Transparent")
        elif pic.shape[2] == 4:
            imgType.append("non-Transparent")
            print("NoTransparent!")
        else:
            imgType.append("unrecognized")
            print("unrecognized!")
    except (requests.exceptions.ConnectionError, requests.exceptions.MissingSchema):
        imgType.append('Down or No Img')
        print('Non URL or Down')
    except (requests.exceptions.Timeout):
        imgType.append('timeout')
        print('timeout')


df["imgType"] = imgType
df.to_csv('/path/to/output.csv')
```

Could someone help me solving this? It is probably related to requests exceptions. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just add a simple check?:

```
for x in urls:
    if x == '': # or some other option to check for the blank urls
        continue
    try:
        pic = plt.imread(x)
        ... etc. with your code
```

Comment: Thanks, I added the ` if x == ' ':` step (see below). But it still throws the same error indicating that something is wrong with this bit `pic = plt.imread(x)`. Would you know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If `x` is actually blank, then that row should never get to execute `pic = plt.imread(x)` but would continue onto the next row of our data. Is the row maybe not empty but a whitespace or something (like a space or tab)?